# Javascript diamond inheritance structure

Tags: javascript, inheritance

Using node but Looking for a way around diamond inheritance in JavaScript:

```
var util = require('util');

function Base(example_value) {
  console.log(example_value);
  this.example_property = example_value;
  this.example_method = function() { ... };
}

function Foo(settings) {
  var f = settings.f;
  Base.call(x);
  this.settings = settings;
}

util.inherits(Foo, Base);

function Bar(settings) {
  var b = settings.b;
  Base.call(b);
  this.settings = settings;
}

util.inherits(Bar, Base);

var foo = new Foo({f: 'bar'});
// 'bar' gets printed and I can call methods from Base..
foo.example_method();
var bar = new Bar({b: 'foo'});
// 'foo' gets printed and I can call methods from Base..
bar.example_method();
```

No problems here..but I then need to make everything that is available in Foo and Bar (and Base) in another all encompassing object:

```
function Top(settings) {
  Foo.call(this, settings);
  Bar.call(this, settings);
}

util.inherits(Top, Foo);
util.inhertis(Top, Bar);

var top = new Top({some: 'value'});
```

'value' gets printed twice which isn't what I was after. Doing inheritance like this probably isn't the best way so looking for alternatives / suggestions to deal with this diamond shape structure.

P.S. Haven't included the original code but modified to hopefully simplify - I've done this by hand, don't think there are any mistakes but the point I'm trying to get across should be there.

Comment: I don't see how "value" is printed at all, as the "settings" object has neither an "f" nor a "b" property.

Comment: @Pointy: `f` and `b` are set in the constructor parameters (e.g. `var foo = new Foo({f: 'bar'});`).

Comment: @Cory yes, and the function "Top" is invoked with an object having a single property named "some".  The "Top" function passes on the object it's passed to both "Foo" and "Bar".

Comment: @Pointy: Ok, I see. Given that "'value' gets printed twice" I assume that the example code is just wrong.

Comment: Apologies, the example_value gets printed twice. Thanks for picking this up though

Comment: @gratz Why do you need `Top` to inherit from both `Foo` and `Bar`? They both do the exact same thing: they call `Base` and then set `this.settings` to the `settings` object. In fact, why do you need a separate `Foo` and `Bar` at all when both of them do the exact same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use delegation?

```
function Top(settings) {
  this.foo = new Foo(settings);
  this.bar = new Bar(settings);
}

Top.prototype.conflictingMethod = function() {
   // use either this.foo or this.bar
}
Top.prototype.anotherMethod = function() {
   return this.foo.anotherMethod();
}
```

You could also use mixins, but you need to add it to your class system. Ext-JS supports mixins http://www.sencha.com/learn/sencha-class-system

```
// My/sample/CanSing.js
Ext.define('My.sample.CanSing', {
    sing: function(songName) {
        alert("I'm singing " + songName);
    }
});

// My/sample/CanPlayGuitar.js
Ext.define('My.sample.CanPlayGuitar', {
    playGuitar: function() {
        alert("I'm playing guitar");
    }
});

// My/sample/CanComposeSongs.js
Ext.define('My.sample.CanComposeSongs', {
    composeSongs: function() {
        alert("I'm composing songs");

        return this;
    }
});

// My/sample/CoolGuy.js
Ext.define('My.sample.CoolGuy', {
    extend: 'My.sample.Person',
    mixins: {
        canSing: 'My.sample.CanSing',
        canPlayGuitar: 'My.sample.CanPlayGuitar'
    }
});

// My/sample/Musician.js
Ext.define('My.sample.Musician', {
    extend: 'My.sample.Person',
    mixins: {
        canSing: 'My.sample.CanSing',
        canPlayGuitar: 'My.sample.CanPlayGuitar',
        canComposeSongs: 'My.sample.CanComposeSongs'
    }
});

// app.js
var nicolas = new My.sample.CoolGuy("Nicolas");
nicolas.sing("November Rain"); // alerts "I'm singing November Rain"
```

Answer (score 1):

That's totally impossible; Javascript does not support multiple inheritance.

In particular, you cannot have a single object that inherits from two prototypes.

Instead, you can manually copy all of the functions from both prototypes to your prototype.  (eg, using a mixin or extends method)

Comment: The OP doesn't really need it to inherit two prototypes, mixins could be used, no?

Comment: @JuanMendes: Yes; I was thinking of mentioning that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how attached you are to classical inheritance but one way to avoid multiple inheritance (and the diamond inheritance issue) is to use **mixins** (mix in). In layman's: You slap more stuff onto your base class until it does everything you want.

Comment: Example coming? Otherwise, it should be a comment

Comment: There is no example coming, the Internet is full of examples of mixins. I strongly believe this should not be a comment, because it is an answer. It answers the question: how do I avoid the diamond inheritance problem?

Comment: What about when there are conflicts between multiple mixins? You should explain how mixins avoid this, which is the main problem with multiple inheritance

Comment: That depends on your mixin implementation. You can throw an Error, pick the last implementation, keep the first implementation, enter a while(true) loop and never exit, take over the world and enslave humans for their biomass. - Mixins solve the diamond inheritance issue by not requiring a constructor, conflict resolution is outside the scope of my answer. I don't believe a full textbook reply is warranted, you're welcome to supply your own.

Comment: Thanks to both for your replies, I've been looking into how I can extend or mixin what I need to achieve here and have come up with a variety of ways to do it. One I have come up with is available here: http://pastebin.com/An2UbzRA

Comments and opinions are very much appreciated

Comment: @gratz Your example shows that delegation (what I suggested) works for your case. http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-inheritance-with-delegation

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers which are all valid and I will up vote. I've put together a more useful and real world example which seems to do the job so I've provided here as *an* answer, but it looks like there's quite a few ways of doing this:

```
function TXObject(settings) {
  this.transmit = function(data) {
    // Transmit data using settings
    console.log('Transmitting data: ' + data);
  }
}

function RXObject(settings) {
  this.receive = function(data) {
    // Receive data using settings
    console.log('Receiving data: ' + data);
  }
}



function Device(settings) {
  this.settings = settings;
}

Device.prototype.asTransmitter = function() {
  var txInstance = new TXObject(this.settings);
  this.transmit = txInstance.transmit.bind(txInstance);
  // Alternatively to wrap txInstance.transmit and add functionality..
  // this.transmit = function() { txInstance.transmit(...); }
  return this;
}

Device.prototype.asReceiver = function() {
  var rxInstance = new RXObject(this.settings);
  this.receive = rxInstance.receive.bind(rxInstance);
  // Same thing for receive..
  // this.receive = function() { rxInstance.receive(...); }
  return this;
}

Device.prototype.asTransceiver = function() {
  this.asTransmitter();
  this.asReceiver();
  return this;
}

var d = new Device({foo: 'bar'});
console.log(d);
var tx = new Device({foo: 'bar'}).asTransmitter();
console.log(tx);
var rx = new Device({foo: 'bar'}).asReceiver();
console.log(rx);
var txrx = new Device({foo: 'bar'}).asTransceiver();
console.log(txrx);

tx.transmit('hello');
rx.receive('world');

txrx.transmit('hello');
txrx.receive('world');
```

Thanks again!